# Remember password after `sudo -i`

Tags: sudo

If I do `sudo <command>` and enter the password, my Debian Squeeze remembers the fact I passed the password and never asks for it for i.e. 15 minutes.

But if I do `sudo -i` and then `exit`, the system does **not** remembers the password and asks for it all  over again every time I use `sudo -i`. Doing just once `sudo <command>` makes the system not ask for password even for a next `sudo -i`.

Here are the scenarios I've described above:

First one:

1. login (by SSH),
2. `sudo <command>`: system's asking for the password,
3. `sudo -i`: system **is not** asking for the password.

Second one:

1. login (by SSH),
2. `sudo -i`: system's asking for the password,
3. `exit`
4. `sudo -i`: system's **again** asking for the password.

Doing something beetween 2. and 3. makes the system remember the password.

What is the reason of such a behaviour? Is it possible to make the system remember the password (fact I passed it) also after using `sudo -i`?

Comment: If I do `sudo -i`, immediately `exit` or `logout` and then again `sudo -i`, the password is properly remembered and the second sudo command doesn't ask for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sudoers(5) man page:

> As a special case, if sudo's -i option (initial login) is specified, sudoers will initialize the environment
>   regardless of the value of env_reset.
>   The DISPLAY, PATH and TERM variables remain unchanged; HOME, MAIL, SHELL, USER, and LOGNAME are set based on the target
>   user.  On Linux and AIX systems the contents of /etc/environment are also included.  All other environment variables are removed

The fact that USER is being set, would likely mean that regardless of your passwd success, that counter is getting reset.

There are other knowledge points in that documentation you should be aware of as well.

Comment: And what about the fact "Doing sth beetween 2. and 3. makes the system remember the password."? Doing sth changes the 'counter'?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know what 'sth' means.  But if it means 'steps' then then why does it not ask for the password between the steps?  Because step 2 you are not using the -i and so it remembers the password, in the third step, then the rules apply according to the documentation.  Once the exit is done, you are changing environments by changing the shell.

Comment: sth = something

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question at all, even though accepted.

Comment: Doesn't answer which question?  There were two.

Comment: It doesn't answer why `sudo` remembers that he's already authenticated in the first case and doesn't in the second case. Nor does it answer how to avoid that behavior. I can't reproduce the behavior on my system, so either his tests are wrong or his system's behavior is different than mine. But my best guess is that it has *nothing* to do with the environment in the `sudo` process nor in the shell started by `sudo`.

Comment: It operates the same on my system as well.  Given the exact sequence of events. The timeout setting in `/etc/sudoers` I have not seen, perhaps he made some changes there regarding that.  The more I look at the answer and the question, the more I agree with you. :)  The environment where the password is remembered is definitely with the parent process.  He also does not indicate the time lapsed between his commands.